# Firefox ignoring Height: 100% css tag on div in favour of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am designing a simple website available below:
-- Removed --

And for the life of me, I can'f figure out why, for the left column (that contains the jQuery UI accordion) I have the height set for 100%, but Firefox ignores this and auto sizes to the size of the accordion content. Everything looks great on Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox...

Now the weird part, is that if I give a custom height to the "accordion" class, or the "scrollable" class, then it will have the correct properties.

The end result would be having the support button static at the bottom of the page, and for the accordion to be 100% of the parent div (which would be the size of the window) and be scrollable (like chrome and safari)

Does anyone out there have any information here?

Comment: i tried this change, it works. hope it helps you to find the issue !!  `<table class="main-table">
 <tbody style="height: 100%;"><tr style="display: table-row; height: 100%;">
  <td class="list-view" style="opacity: 1; height: 100%;">`

Comment: @KishoreSahas This Worked! I never thought that firefox would require me to set each table structure individually... Especially since <tbody> was added automatically by the post-process, but I guess this is best practice. Thank you so much for pointing this out! I will be putting together a patch for this and pushing it very shortly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below, and it works in all browsers.

set `height:100%` for the `tbody` , `tr` and `td`.

```
<table class="main-table">
  <tbody style="height: 100%;">
    <tr style="display: table-row; height: 100%;">
      <td class="list-view" style="opacity: 1; height: 100%;">
```

Comment: This is it :) Thank you kind sir for finding this, I was scratching my head for hours thinking it was my javascript or the Jquery UI css

Comment: Cool. Your solution works on Firefox 38. But it fails in MSIE11. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

well I know it won't (directly) help you but here your main problem is that overflow: auto doesn't work on firefox...

Comment: Thank you for looking into this Gini, even after the disable of the Overflow: auto there is nothing that will help :( Incredibly stuck here!

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you are setting the height to 100%, where are you doing so? I assume that you're adding this into your ***style.css*** file. The jQuery UI has auto properties for height set that you need to override. Taken straight from the ***jquery-ui.css*** file:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
  padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-icons {
 padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
    border-top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

The best place to start would be to start editing these features in the jquery-ui.css file (I see you downloaded the file rather than using the CDN. Border-top is your best bet). Try to get the height to fit what you want. When using bootstrap, materialize, etc you often have to go in and edit the downloaded css file because you're changes won't override theirs. Do a quick text search for "accordion" in the jquery-ui.css file and you can quickly find wherever they're defining height properties for the element. Hope this helps.

Comment: Blondie, thank you for getting back to me with such a detailed response! I have looked into the jquery-ui.css file and have found only "overflow: auto" to be affecting the layout in a vertical aspect. I would have hoped by setting this to "scroll" it would set the height to 100% and then scroll the overflow... but this is not the case here. But yes, I am setting height: 100% in style.css under ".scrollable" to imply that the div was scrollable (but apparently not in firefox)

Comment: Very interesting, I would think that the margin-top: -8px would be affecting the height of the element. when you look inside your ***jquery-ui.css*** do you see these same pre-sets that I pasted above?